# Distances over a rectangular parallelepiped

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, geometry

It is given a rectangular parallelepiped $3\times4\times5$. Which are the farthest points from a given vertex, provided one can only walk on the surface of the parallelepiped?

Comment: Which given vertex? Or are you after 8 answers (with some repeated)?

Comment: Are you looking for the shortest distance between two vertices that are the furthest apart in 3-space? If not, what's to stop an answer from walking across the same surface multiple times in order to extend the length of the path?

Comment: I am looking for the shortest distance between two points on the surface of a parallelepiped (provided that one of those points is one vertex, and that you can only move on the surface of the parallelepiped).

Comment: @Ali Through mirroring and rotations, all vertices would be considered equivalent don't you think?

Comment: @Trenin Yes, I think you are right yes.

Comment: I say please re-open: this puzzle really is puzzle-like in nature, going by the 3rd of the 3 bullet-points xnor listed at "So, what makes something a math puzzle rather than math problem? I think there's a few features." in the answer here: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/are-math-textbook-style-problems-on-topic

Comment: I see that you have edited the answer below: thank you. How did you found the value $2+10/13$? Since this question has been closed, I have transferred to math.stackechange (where an answer was given, but that answer is wrong). Would you like to contribute? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864153/distances-over-a-rectangular-parallelepiped

Comment: Regarding the reopening: did you try to flag the question, in order to have the attention of the moderators?

Comment: @RosieF I don't think your answer is correct, since you can get to (5,4,z) in at most sqrt((4+z)² + 5²) for any z. See my answer on math, I think the obvious answer really is the right answer here (although proving it is not trivial, and there are some cuboids for which the obvious answer is incorrect, e.g. 1x1x2).

Comment: @zar Sorry -- I didn't realise that flagging was the right thing to do.

Comment: @ffao & zar. Yes, now I see that I'm wrong. I overlooked a route. BTW y=4, z=2 10/13 maximises $\min((8-z)^2+(y+3)^2, (5+z)^2+y^2)$

Comment: So, which are the cuboids with the property that the obious route is not the shortest one?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I got the terms wrong here but I think :

> The farthest point in a rectangular parallelpiped from a vertex is the vertex at the other end of a space diagonal that goes through the given vertex.
>  The distance is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$
>  So in this case $\sqrt{3^2+4^2+5^2}$ which is about $7.07$

---

Let the cuboid be $x=0,\dots,5; y=0,\dots,4; z=0,\dots,3$. And let the starting vertex be $(0,0,0)$.

> It might be thought that the furthest point is the opposite vertex $(5,4,3)$. The shortest route to that vertex crosses an edge of length $5$, and its length is $\sqrt{(4+3)^2+5^2}=\sqrt{74}$.
>
>  However, there is a $z_0=2\frac{10}{13}$ where, for $z\geqslant z_0$, the distance to $(5,4,z)$ by the shortest route is $\sqrt{(3+y)^2+(8-z)^2}$. For $z=z_0$, this distance $= \sqrt{76 \frac{61}{169}} \sim 8.7384750812$.
>
>  (So I think this puzzle really does count as a puzzle because its correct answer is different from the one you might at first think.)

Comment: If you reverse 7.07 you get LOL

Comment: @Lordofdark. You got too much spare time and a wild imagination. 707...I mean LOL

Comment: I'm sorry, I left an important information in the keyboard: you are allowed to only walk on the surface of the parallelepiped. I will edit the question.